# How do I send a model that was clicked on within a ItemView to another ItemView that is on the same page?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection of Tools displayed as a CompositeView. Each of the rendered items in this collection is an ItemView. The name of the region that holds these is called toolNameRegion.

I have another region named toolDetailsRegion in that page and it has its supposed to render the attributes of the clicked tool in the toolNameRegion.

Here is the view:

```
@Tools.module "AboutApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Show.Layout extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
    template: JST['backbone/apps/about/templates/about']

    regions:
      toolNameRegion:  "#tool-name"
      toolDetailsRegion: "#tool-details"

  class Show.Tool extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    template: JST['backbone/apps/about/templates/_tool']
    tagName: "li"

    events:
      "click a.tool-link" : -> 
        @trigger "tool-name:link:clicked", @model # How the hell do I pass this to the Show.ToolDetail class?
        console.log @model # shows the model attributes that was clicked

  class Show.Tools extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
    template: JST['backbone/apps/about/templates/tools']
    itemView: Show.Tool
    itemViewContainer: "ul"

    triggers:
      "click .tool-link" : "tool:link:clicked"

  class Show.ToolDetail extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    template: JST['backbone/apps/about/templates/tool_details']
    itemView: Show.Tool

    onShow: -> console.log "onShow"
    onClose: -> console.log "onClose"
```

Here is the controller:

```
@Tools "AboutApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Show.Controller =

    showAbout: ->
      tools = App.request "get:tools"
      @aboutLayout = @getAboutLayout()

      @aboutLayout.on "show", =>
        @showTools tools
        @showInitialTool tools

      App.mainRegion.show @aboutLayout

    showTools: (tools) ->
      toolsView = @getToolsView tools   
      console.log toolsView

      toolsView.on "tool:link:clicked", (tool) =>
        console.log "model: #{tool}"
        tool = @getInitialToolView tool
        @aboutLayout.toolDetailsRegion.show tool

    @aboutLayout.toolNameRegion.show toolsView


  getToolsView: (tools) ->
    new Show.Tools
      collection: tools

  showInitialTool: (tools) ->
    initial_tool = tools.at(1) 
    toolView = @getInitialToolView initial_tool
    @aboutLayout.toolDetailsRegion.show toolView

  getToolDetailsView:  ->
    App.request "tool:detail:view"

  toolDetailsRegion: ->
    toolDetailView = @getInitialToolView 
    @about.toolDetailsRegion.show toolDetailView

  getInitialToolView: (tool) ->
    new Show.ToolDetail
      model: tool

  getAboutLayout: ->
    new Show.Layout
```

How do I pass in the @model (model that was clicked on) to the controller so @model can be passed to the view class Show.ToolDetail so that the toolDetailsRegion can be updated dynamically?

Here's my Entities (resources):

```
@Tools.module "Entities", (Entities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Entities.Tool extends Backbone.Model

  class Entities.ToolCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Entities.Tool
    url: -> Routes.tools_path()

  API =

    setTools: (tools) ->
      new Entities.ToolCollection (tools)

    getToolEntities: ->
      tools = new Entities.ToolCollection()
      tools.fetch
        reset: true
      tools

    App.reqres.setHandler "set:tools", (tools) ->
      API.setTools tools

    App.reqres.setHandler "tool:entities", ->
      API.getToolEntities()
```

Thanks for your response @David Sulc. It is still not passing the model through. Maybe I'm not formatting it correctly?

The way I grab the model from the view:

```
class Show.Tool extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  template: JST['backbone/apps/about/templates/_tool']
  tagName: "li"

  events:
    "click a.tool-link" : -> 
      App.request "get:new:tool", @model
      console.log @model
```

In the controller:

```
 showTools: (tools) ->
    toolsView = @getToolsView tools   
    console.log toolsView

    toolsView.on "tool:link:clicked", (tool) =>
      console.log "model retrieved from click: #{tool}" # comes up undefined; how to obtain?
      tool = App.request "get:new:tool" # could this be the path, but since tool is undefined, won't work? 
      new_tool = @getInitialToolView tool
      @aboutLayout.toolDetailsRegion.show new_tool

  @aboutLayout.toolNameRegion.show toolsView
```

Thanks to @David Sulc for showing me the way!

**In the controller:**

```
  showTools: (tools) ->
    toolsView = @getToolsView tools   
    console.log toolsView

    Tools.AboutApp.Show.on "tool-name:link:clicked", (tool) =>
      console.log tool.get('name')
      new_tool = @getInitialToolView tool
      @aboutLayout.toolDetailsRegion.show new_tool
```

**In the view code:**

```
  class Show.Tool extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    template: JST['backbone/apps/about/templates/_tool']
    tagName: "li"

    events:
      "click a.tool-link" : -> 
        Tools.AboutApp.Show.trigger "tool-name:link:clicked", @model
        console.log @model

  class Show.ToolDetail extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    template: JST['backbone/apps/about/templates/tool_details']
    itemView: Show.Tool
    Tools.AboutApp.Show.on "tool-name:link:clicked", (tool) =>
      console.log tool

    onShow: -> console.log "onShow"
    onClose: -> console.log "onClose"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would these app wide event be in the tool module? Or in the controller? Or in the layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use events, scoped to your current module. Trigger the event in your view with

```
Tools.AboutApp.Show.trigger "my:event", @model
```

Then, in your controller you can listen for that event and update your other view:

```
Tools.AboutApp.Show.on "my:event", (model) ->
    console.log model
```

The syntax you've used in the Show.Tools view will be limited in scope to the item view (and to a certain extent its collection view). Since you need to pass data between different views, we need to widen the scope, and therefore use the call as above: trigger and listen for events in the `Tools.AboutApp.Show` scope.

In your view:

```
events:
  "click a.tool-link" : -> 
    Tools.AboutApp.Show.trigger "tool-name:link:clicked", @model
```

And in your detail view:

```
Tools.AboutApp.Show.on "tool-name:link:clicked", (tool) =>
  console.log "model retrieved from click: #{tool}"
```

Notice we need to use the same scope and same trigger name.

Comment: Thanks for your response @David Sulc. It is still not passing the model through.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It doesn't seem like you're using the proper event scope, and your trigger names are inconsistent.

Comment: you're correct about scope, and the code I put above re: naming the event was rushed on my part. I've almost there, and as soon as I get it working I'll mark the answer as accepted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: thanks for your help ... model is passing perfectly, and your answer is marked as acceptable. Now I need to figure the syntax to update the details view ... haha